# Spark Streaming crashes to Kafka Ran out of messages before reaching ending offset exception

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

In one of our streaming usecase; one of our sensor software is sending 5 each ~20MB JSON messages/Sec to Kafka topic with 50 partitions, when spark streaming is trying to read messages from Kafka it crashes with below exception.
In order to understand situation better, we manage to make the sensor software send only 1 20MB message/Sec but spark application crashes with the same error.Please let me know if I am missing anything that need to be done to handle such scenario.

We have the following config

-Kafka 0.9.0 server.properties

```
message.max.bytes=60000000 
replica.fetch.max.bytes=120000000
```

-Spark 1.6.1 Config DirectAPI on yarn

```
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
      "security.protocol" -> "SASL_PLAINTEXT",
      "group.id" -> groupid,
      "metadata.broker.list" -> kafkaBrokerList,
      "max.partition.fetch.bytes" -> "60000000")
```

-Spark Submit

```
spark-submit \
--verbose \
--master yarn-cluster \
--num-executors 3  \
--executor-memory 7g \
--executor-cores 3 \
--conf spark.driver.memory=1024m  \
--conf spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled=false \
--conf spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition=3 \
--conf spark.streaming.concurrentJobs=3 \
--conf spark.speculation=true \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache=true \
--files kafka_jaas.conf#kafka_jaas.conf,user.headless.keytab#user.headless.keytab \
--driver-java-options "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./kafka_jaas.conf -Dhttp.proxyHost=PROXY_IP -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=PROXY_IP -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/user/spark-log4j/log4j-topic_name-driver.properties" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./kafka_jaas.conf -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/user/spark-log4j/log4j-topic_name-executor.properties" \
--class com.spark.demo.StreamProcessor /home/user/demo.jar /tmp/data/out 60 KAFKA_BROKER:6667 "groupid" topic_name
```

-Exception:

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, IP_HOST): java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Ran out of messages before reaching ending offset 197 for topic x_topic_3 partition 24 start 196. This should not happen, and indicates that messages may have been lost
at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:179)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.getNext(KafkaRDD.scala:211)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:308)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1335)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1335)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1881)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1881)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Driver stacktrace
```

:

Answer (score 0):

add `("fetch.message.max.bytes" -> "20971520")` in kafkaParams, you can find the source code in `ConsumerConfig.scala#114` (Spark 1.6.2)

Comment: I am using DirectAPI which uses simple consumer, for simple consumer `max.partition.fetch.bytes` is the setting to fetch max message byte right if I am correct.

Comment: In KafkaRDD.scala#fetecBatch (line 190), you can find `.addFetch(part.topic, part.partition, requestOffset, kc.config.fetchMessageMaxBytes)`,  go the the `kc.config.fetchMessageMaxBytes` you will find the *key* is **fetch.message.max.bytes**.

Comment: Then What is the difference between `max.partition.fetch.bytes` and 'fetch.message.max.byte' with respect to DirectAPI

Comment: As I know, `max.partition.fetch.bytes` is the higher setting, and `fetch.message.max.byte` is the lower setting. When reading data from kafka with DirectAPI, first check `max.partition.fetch.bytes`, then check `fetch.message.max.bytes`

Comment: Ok so you mean `max.partition.fetch.bytes` is lower bound of message size and `fetch.message.max.bytes` is upper bound message size?

Comment: I think the upper bound message size if min(`max.partition.fetch.bytes`, `fetch.message.max.bytes`)